# Why is my useState value is undefined after fetching? It seems like useState doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MainContent() {
    const [objectsArr, setObjectsArr] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchMyAPI() {
            let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3030/pickedObjects')

            response = await response.json();
            setObjectsArr(response)
        }
        fetchMyAPI()
    }, [])

    const contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

    return (
        <ul className="content row">
            {objectsArr.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <ContentItem className="item" item={item} />
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default MainContent;
```

I am trying to render an array of elements, using useEffect that calls a fetch, and the I use **.map()** to directly render them

So when I try to run this I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

which is a **setObjectsArr** initial value. So is the **setObjectsArr(response)** in the useEffect not being set, or it's being set too early?

How can I fix that?

I tried almost everything but I cant find the reason why it doesn't work.The fetch itself is okay, it returns a decent value, but useState doesn't set it.

Comment: What do you mean "after fetching"? You explicitly set it to null _before_ fetching, that's why it's null (not undefined).

Comment: The error is thrown during the initial rendering, when `objectsArr` is still `null`. You need to render something else while the fetch response is still loading.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Because you're defining the initial value as `null`:

```
const [objectsArr, setObjectsArr] = useState(null);
```

And trying to call `.map()` on it:

```
objectsArr.map((item) => {
```

This all happens before any API interaction takes place.  The result of the API call may indeed be an array (we don't know, but presumably that's what you expect), and state will be updated to that value at a later time.  But until then, you need a component which can render without error.

It sounds like an empty array is a more sensible default value:

```
const [objectsArr, setObjectsArr] = useState([]);
```

Or, alternatively, check the value before using it.  For example, using optional chaining:

```
objectsArr?.map((item) => {
```

Or checking for falsy-ness:

```
objectsArr && objectsArr.map((item) => {
```

Comment: I would say that it is better to keep the variable initialized as `null` and handle the "null case" when rendering.  Otherwise you don't know the difference between "have not got data back from API yet" vs. "got a result but it was empty".  The only time I think it makes sense to have a non-null initial value for data that will be fetched asynchronously is when dealing with `<input>` fields.  The frequently require an initial value of `""` or will give errors.

Comment: @GregFenton: Possibly, yes.  I also like the pattern of an explicit `isLoading` state to define whether the operation is still awaiting results, separate from the data value state.

Comment: Yes, that too....but do you want an `isLoading` for every field in a multi-field , multi-fetch component?  Ultimately it comes down to: `null` is a perfectly good value that means "we don't know yet"....don't code `null` away.  Leverage it!  Don't be scared of `null`....don't shun `null`.  They are your friend!!  

Comment: Ok, so I made a little bit of a crutch, but it works now. The problem was not about not getting null/undefined value, but to render the objects right after the fetch. I wanted to call .map() right after the fetch, so it'll render everything correctly. Thanks, anyway

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I refactored everything a little bit, not sure if it's the right way, but works fine:

`const [renderedObjects, setRenderedObjects] = useState([]);`

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData('http://localhost:3030/pickedObjects');
}, []);

const getData = async (apiUrl) => {
    const data = fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            setRenderedObjects(json.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <ContentItem className="item" item={item} />
                )
            }))
        });
}

const contentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

return (
    <ul className="content row">
        {renderedObjects}
    </ul>
);
```

Now, my `setRenderedObjects` useState value is set directly in the fetch.

Comment: Storing *JSX* in state, while there may be a valid use case for it somewhere, is generally considered bad practice.  It's *almost always* better to just store *data* in state and render the JSX in the `return` of the component.  At the very least, it makes the component simpler and much easier to debug.

Comment: I know it, but then rendering willl be executed before fetch is done, therefore nothing will be rendered.